# Disable search for PR builds in read the docs

Tags: python, github, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm having a python project on RTD that takes quite a while to build. Sphinx takes about 8-9 minutes and after that the RTD build sits another 20 minutes on this step before it completes:

```
The HTML pages are in _build/html.
Updating searchtools for Read the Docs search...
```

This means I spent around 30 minutes waiting for the doc CI. I'm having PR builds enabled (awesome feature!), and for these, I don't really need a search engine. Within the PR I know what changes I expect to see in the docs (if any) and where they should appear.

Is it possible to disable building a search index for PR builds?

Comment: What project is it? Happy to have a look :)

Comment: Also, this might be a good candidate for an issue at https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/

Comment: Thanks, @astrojuanlu . The project is called [scikit-bot](https://scikit-bot.org/en/latest/) and runs under the RTD slug [robotics-python](https://readthedocs.org/projects/robotics-python/). I'll cross-post an issue on GH.

Comment: For future readers: the answer is "it can't be done, yet", and now there is an issue tracking the feature request.